# Using python look behind to isolate part of string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use regex to match just part of a string and I'm not sure where I'm messing up the syntax.

```
string = 'Item key: 0.1234 xY ( -2.6 GMc)'
match = re.search(r'(?<=\( )([^ GMc]*)', string)
print(match)
```

The value I am trying to get is -2.6 (without '') but what I am actually getting is
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(22, 26), match='-2.6'>

I know re.findall() for instance will create a list of values that match as a list even if there is one item in the list but that what I was trying to work around with search and look forward/behind.

I am using python 3.4.3 on win32

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), which says that it returns a MatchObject and includes a link to the documentation for [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject), which explains how to use MatchObjects to extract what you want?

Comment: Used print(match.group(0)) instead and it worked, thanks.

Comment: @BroccoliSoup but your regex  won't work for all the cases. Check with this input  `Item key: 0.1234 xY ( -G2.6 GMc)`

Comment: My input data doesn't contain any -G2.6 but sadly it does contain some that are (-12.6 GMc) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use positive lookahead assertion. `[^ GMc]*` in your regex matches any character but not of space or `G` or `M` or `c`, zero or more times. That is, it would stop matching once it finds any one of the  pattern present inside the character class. Not the whole `GMc` .

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'Item key: 0.1234 xY ( -2.6 GMc)'
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\( ).*?(?= GMc)', string).group()
'-2.6'
```

`(?<=\( )` looks immediate after to `space(` and match `.*?` any character zero or more times until the string `<space>GMc` is found.

Comment: Thanks, I had a few that were (-12.6 GMc) etc. so I edited the regex to stop looking for a space after ( and it parsed. Its working now, thanks.